# parse.com API and other databases?

Tags: database, mobile, authentication, amazon-web-services, parse-platform

Is it recommended to use the parse.com API for a mobile application while using other databases such as amazon simpleDB for most of the app back-end data?

Basically, parse.com would only be used for its login/register user system.

That leads to some questions such as "**can our own server check a parse.com sessionToken validity before returning data?**"

Anyway, anyone has used parse.com in combination with a bigger cloud service such as AWS?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> can our own server check a parse.com sessionToken validity before returning data?

I think you can achieve this using [Parse's Cloud Code](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide).

You could try something like:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("validateUser", function(request, response) {
  var myname = request.params.myname;
  var mypass = request.params.mypass;
        Parse.User.logIn(myname, mypass, {
            success: function(user) {
                // Do stuff after successful login.
            },
            error: function(user, error) {
                // The login failed. Check error to see why.
            }
        });
});
```

And test it with the following curl (be sure to replace the App ID and Rest API Key):

```
curl -X POST \
    -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: <YOUR_PARSE_APP_ID_HERE>" \
    -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: <YOUR_PARSE_REST_API_KEY_HERE>" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{"myname":"johnPooter", "mypass":"pooter123"}' \
    https://api.parse.com/1/functions/validateUser
```

As to whether it is recommended or not to use other back-ends with Parse: I think it is fine but it defeats the purpose of using Parse.  Parse is good when you are trying to throw something together quickly and don't want to invest resources towards solving common back-end problems.

Comment: Thanks! Regarding your last sentence. I see your point but the thing is I don't want to develop a proper login system myself (email confirmation, recovery, reset, login with Facebook, iOS/Android/Javascript, etc)... But that is the only thing I need from parse. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, it definitely makes sense.  Parse already developed a great login system that you can leverage, so why not do it?  My only concern would be potential service disruptions.  Parse is generally good about this but I do remember a time on June 11th when our app went down for 4+ hours (http://blog.parse.com/2013/06/12/summary-of-the-june-11th-service-disruption/).  BTW, I found that Parse does have User Session Management (https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#webapp-users).  Hope that helps.